# Use Openpyxl Style Objects to set Excel cell style

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I extracted the font object of an Excel cell, which looks like this:

```
<openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object> Parameters: 
name='Calibri', 
charset=None, 
family=2.0, 
b=False, 
i=False, 
strike=None, 
outline=None, 
shadow=None, 
condense=None, 
color=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object> Parameters: 
    rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=1, tint=0.0, type='theme', 
extend=None, 
sz=12.0, 
u='single', 
vertAlign=None, 
scheme='minor'
```

It consists of 15 properties of which one is another style object (color object).

Is it possible to use this font object to set the font of an Excel cell without having to extract each property and apply it individually.

Something like

```
cell.font = <openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object> Parameters: name='Calibri', charset=None, family=2.0, b=False, i=False, strike=None, outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object> Parameters: rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=1, tint=0.0, type='theme', extend=None, sz=12.0, u='single', vertAlign=None, scheme='minor'
```

Instead of

```
cell.font = Font(size=12)
cell.font = Font(underline="single")
etc.
```

*Disclaimer: I'm using openpyxl 2.5.12 and I'm unable to upgrade.*

Comment: Perhaps a [Named Style](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#creating-a-named-style) would useful to you. Create it then apply to as many cells as you wish.

Comment: hmm, no that's unfortunately not it. But I might need it in a different context. So thanks anyway

Comment: What I did was, I extracted the font objects of all Cells in the excel table. So I have a lot of those objects. And now I want to recreate the Excel file with the information from those objects.

Comment: I therefore edited the string to this: Font(
name="Calibri", 
charset=None, 
family=2.0, 
b=True, 
i=False, 
strike=None, 
outline=None, 
shadow=None, 
condense=None, 
color=Color(rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=1, tint=0.0, type="theme"), 
extend=None, 
sz=12.0, 
u="single", 
vertAlign=None, 
scheme="minor"
) But it is currently still destroying my Excel file when I try to change the font with it..

Comment: A font object is a font object. However, you need to understand that once they're assigned their immutable. So, if you want to change attributes you need to create a copy and work with that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's what I came to do. Even though I'm not trying to change any attributes, I had to extract all the attributes from the the object and created a new one like this:

Comment: cell.font = Font(name=df["name"][1], charset=df["charset"][1], family=df["fam"][1], b=df["b"][1], i=df["i"][1], strike=df["strike"][1], outline=df["outl"][1], shadow=df["shadow"][1], condense=df["condense"][1], color=Color(rgb=df["rgb"][1], indexed=df["indexed"][1], auto=df["auto"][1], theme=df["theme"][1], tint=df["tint"][1], type=df["type"][1]), extend=df["ext"][1], sz=df["sz"][1], u=df["u"][1], vertAlign=df["vertA"][1], scheme=df["scheme"][1])

Comment: editing the string of the original object as I did before does not work